# pdf to json libraries

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a library which converts pdf to json. Basically in that json the paragraph heading is the and the value is the content of paragraph. Is there any python library for that ? I am already using pdfminer but that just converts to plain text. It cannot persist the structure/organisation of the document. For now it is ok to not read images and table although if there is a library to do that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> It cannot persist the structure/organisation of the document.

To tackle this, you can look at pdftotext (which comes by default in case you are on a linux system). It preserves the exact layout of the pdf page. You will have to specify the layout option.

> For now it is ok to not read images and table although if there is a library to do that would be great.

Table extraction is a different(and more complicated) problem. However if the tables are not that complicated, you can use Camelot/Tabula to extract those. I would suggest you to go with Camelot as it also provides a lot of tunable parameters that you change for your case specific tables. (More details :[Camelot](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)  )